# android animator - scale view to the center (Froyo)

Tags: android-animation, android

I have a View in my android app which I want to scale & fade away to the center of it. So far I have the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true" >

<scale
    android:duration="1500"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="0"
    android:toYScale="0" />

<alpha
    android:duration="1500"
    android:fromAlpha="1"
    android:toAlpha="0" />

</set>
```

yet that leads to the unwanted effect the text is "scaled away" to the upper left corner. How can I correct this so it is scaling to the center of the view? I need this for API >=8 .

Thanks for any hint.

Martin

Comment: consider http://nineoldandroids.com/ instead of old one animation api

Comment: thx a lot tabby - on the way to check it, looks promising

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself, pivotX and pivotY are doing the trick

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true" >

<scale
    android:duration="1500"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0"
    android:toYScale="0" />

<alpha
    android:duration="1500"
    android:fromAlpha="1"
    android:toAlpha="0" />

</set>
```